# Cross-validation of a FittedModel

Tags: fitting

Although I would know how to perform cross-validation tests after fitting a model using a function like NonLinearModelFit, I wonder if there is a way to do this providing the right parameters to the FittedModel.  If not available, then I think that this would be a good way to improve FittedModel functions in future versions of Mathematica.

Comment: Here you can find information on the meaning of Cross-Validation: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_(statistics)

Comment: [Machine Lerning](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/MachineLearning.html) esp. [`ValidationSet`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ValidationSet.html) might include the tools you are looking for.

Comment: @Karsten7. You are right.  For example, it would be great if PredictorMeasurements[FittedModel,testSet,property] would accept FittedModel as its first parameter but apparently that is not yet possible.